# Cell Fraction Not covering all part of an object

Tags: modeling, objects, cell-fracture

So I tried applying Cell Fracture to a 3D human Model in blender But for some unknown reason the Fracture don't cover the object, it's keeps cutting and leaving out part of the object, specifically the arms from fracturing along with the rest, like the size of the bounding box is not covering the entire object But I don't know where to increase the size of the cell fracture to cover the whole object.

I've tried decreasing the scale of the object but same problem. Does anyone know what I should do here please.

Comment: Please share some screenshots of your Cell fracture setup and result (or simplified file via https://blend-exchange.com with just a body before fracturing) to let us better picture of what is going on ... but it is not the first time when this Aaron failed (that is happening on complex shapes, but usually ends like with missing shards rather than bounding box cut.